# Unexpected result in SELECT CASE WHEN NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select-case

**Schema and data**

I have two tables with the following schema and data:

*#table1:*

```
create table #table1(
    PK int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    [TEXT] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
);

PK    TEXT
1     a
2     b
3     c
4     d
5     e
```

*#table2:*

```
create table #table2(
    PK int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    FK int NOT NULL, 
    [TEXT] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
);

PK    FK    TEXT
1     2     B
2     3     C
```

**Problem**

Now, if I select all from `#table1` and left join `#table2` like this:

```
select 
    #table1.PK,
    (case #table2.[TEXT] when NULL then #table1.[TEXT] else #table2.[TEXT] end) as [TEXT]
from 
    #table1
left join
    #table2 on #table2.FK = #table1.PK
;
```

the output are as following:

```
PK    TEXT
1     NULL
2     B
3     C
4     NULL
5     NULL
```

## Question

I expected the result to be:

```
PK    TEXT
1     a     <
2     B
3     C
4     d     <
5     e     <
```

So why does this happen (or what am I doing wrong) and how can I fix this?

**Source code**

```
if (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table1') is not null) drop table #table1;
if (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table2') is not null) drop table #table2;

create table #table1(PK int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [TEXT] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL);
create table #table2(PK int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, FK int NOT NULL, [TEXT] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL);

insert into #table1 ([TEXT]) VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d'), ('e');
insert into #table2 (FK, [TEXT]) VALUES (2, 'B'), (3, 'C');

select 
    #table1.PK,
    (case #table2.[TEXT] when NULL then #table1.[TEXT] else #table2.[TEXT] end) as [TEXT]
from 
    #table1
left join
    #table2 on #table2.FK = #table1.PK
;

drop table #table1;
drop table #table2;
```

Comment: Use `CASE WHEN IS NULL`--forgot IS.

Comment: @Mihai Thanks for your comment, but this will produce a `incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my perspective this is equivalent of

```
select isnull(table2.text, table1.text) as text from ...
```

Comment: This is much more cleaner, +1.

Comment: You're correct, this fixed it. But it would be interesting to know why my approach is failing.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå - as detailed in my answer, the problem is the way you constructed your case statement. You are effectively making a comparison with NULL when you do `CASE x WHEN NULL THEN...` which will always be false.

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether a field is null or not by `is null`, even though your `case when` is syntactically correct, you should use the other syntactically correct version.

```
case
  when #table2.[TEXT] is null then #table1.[TEXT]
  else #table2.[TEXT]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you have constructed your `CASE` statement. Any `CASE` statement of the form `CASE x WHEN NULL THEN...` is not going to behave as you might initially expect as you are effectively performing a comparison with NULL, which is always false, in your case resulting in always getting `#table2.[TEXT]`.

I think you'd need to do:

```
(CASE WHEN #table2.[TEXT] IS NULL THEN #table1.[TEXT] ELSE #table2.[TEXT] END) AS [TEXT]
```

which is equivalent to `COALESCE`:

```
COALESCE(#table2.[TEXT], #table1.[TEXT]) AS [TEXT]
```